# How to select MIN and MAX from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, query-optimization

I have two tables in postgresql: ITEM (ID, TYPE) and ITEM_DATA (TS, ITEM_ID) in 1:n relation. The first table is small and the second is huge. I would like to know the best way to select min and max from the table ITEM_DATA for each row of a select from the table ITEM. At this moment I have this select, but it's too slow:

```
SELECT 
  I.*,
  (SELECT MIN(ID.TS) FROM ITEM_DATA ID WHERE ID.ITEM_ID=I.ID) AS MIN_TS,
  (SELECT MAX(ID.TS) FROM ITEM_DATA ID WHERE ID.ITEM_ID=I.ID) AS MAX_TS
FROM ITEM I
WHERE I.TYPE = 'X';
```

There is a primary key in the table ITEM_DATA which has two segments: TS and ITEM_ID and there is also an index on the table ITEM which has one segment: TYPE.

Is there a way how to make this query faster?

Comment: How many rows are there in the ITEM table, and how many rows in the ITEM_DATA table? Are there many other columns on ITEM_DATA?

Comment: ITEM has hundreds and ITEM_DATA has hundreds millions

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reverse the order of the columns of the PK on ITEM_DATA.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*, mima.mi, mima.ma
FROM item i
JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT item_id
        , MIN(ts) as mi
        , MAX(ts) as ma
        FROM item_data
        GROUP BY item_id
        ) mima ON mima.item_id = i.id
WHERE i.type = 'X'
        ;
```

And, yes: your query will benefit from an index

```
    CREATE INDEX ON item_data(item_id,ts);
```

Comment: WHERE I.TYPE = 'X' is missing in your answer

Comment: I am sorry, but your solution is like 5000 times slower then my original post even with the index segments switched the way you suggested.

Comment: And what is the selectivity of the `i.type = 'X'` restriction ? And what does the plan show? and what is tour database tuning? and do you have valid statistics ?